# Replace exact matches between cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete all exact words in a cell, that are found in other cell.
Example:

> "Star Performer Uhp 1 215/45R18"

- This is the input cell(called source)

> "89V"

- This is what i want to achieve(by using replace on exact copy of input with words from split)

> "25/45R8 89V"

- This is what i get

The output i mentioned above that i get is from the split method which is not exact as i want it to be. I split the input cell into words dividing by the space.

```
clean = Split(source, " ")
For i = LBound(clean) To UBound(clean)
Cells(h, 8).Replace What:=clean(i), Replacement:=""
```

I want to make it as exact as it can be so for example the number **1** found ins plit will only repleace standalone **1** not in combination like **215** or **45R18**.

Comment: Record a macro using Find and Replace (Ctrl + H) and amend that code?

Comment: Recording a macro using Ctrl + H is too simple and generates too many errors. I have whole macro done i just need to find a way to only replace exact same words as a standalone, not that are part of other word.

Comment: Upload some examples please

Comment: `too simple and generates too many errors` To replace only exact contents, do this. In that dialog box, click options and then select "match entire cell contents". After that simple amend your code to suit your needs. Trust me that is the fastest way to achieve what you want :)

Comment: Have you looked into using the `Find` function together with the `lookat:=xlWhole` argument?

Comment: Thanks Tim, that done the trick for me. Find function really is more useful in exact then replace.